# JSONB not supported in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, doctrine

SO this is my migration code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class ChangeDataTemplateOfActionTableToJsonB extends Migration
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        DB::getDoctrineSchemaManager()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('jsonb', 'string');
    }

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */


    public function up()
    {
        //
         Schema::table('actions', function ( $table) {
             $table->jsonb('data_template')->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Even though I am registering the doctrine correctly it throws this error
[image]

**ERROR**

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                                                                                                                                            
  Unknown column type "jsonb" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Typ  
  es\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgot to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapp  
  ing() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @AlexBlex alright

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the `DoctrineSchemaManager` from the Schema connection the register the mapping like this :

```
$databasePlatform = Schema::getConnection()
                            ->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
                            ->getDatabasePlatform();
$databasePlatform->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('jsonb', 'string');
```

Ps: if it's not working in the `__construct` add the above code to the `up` method.

Comment: Ok take a look at this [thread](https://coderwall.com/p/mo1gew/custom-datatype-in-laravel-schema-builder) if it's working i can update the answer :)